# Parsing URL in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have 2 URL like this:

> http://localhost/gtwhero/public/users/3/subscribers-lists/1/subscribers

> http://localhost/gtwhero/public/users/3/subscribers-lists/

So, URL format is like it:

> {baseURL} +"users/{user_id}/subscribers-lists/"+{id}+"/subscribers"

Or-

> {baseURL} +"users/{user_id}/subscribers-lists/"

and when I run this JS in this 2 pages, because 1page code is included in other page:

```
var baseURL = "http://localhost/gtwhero/public/";
$('#subscribers_list tbody').on( 'click', 'button.details', function () //Handeling Edit Button Click
{
    var data = dataTable.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
    //alert(data['id']);    //id = index of ID sent from server
    window.location = window.location.href +'/'+data['id']+'/subscribers';
});
```

So, it is working for the second URL, but bot working for the first URL.

So, I am getting:

> {baseURL} +"users/{user_id}/subscribers-lists/"+{id}+"/subscribers"

for the second URL, but getting error like this:

> {baseURL} +"users/{user_id}/subscribers-lists/"+{id}+"/subscribers"+{id}+"/subscribers"

for the first URL.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Does the element `#subscribers_list tbody` exist on the DOM of the second page?

Comment: Yes, it exists and working

Comment: Can you update the question with html? Note: A page can have only one id. ie. one `#subscribers_list`

Answer (score 0):

I have done it-

```
var url                     = window.location.href;
var userId                  = (url.match(/\/users\/(\d+)\//) || [])[1];
var subscribers_lists_Id    = (url.match(/\/subscribers-lists\/(\d+)\//) || [])[1];
```